# Scrapy Issue - TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'list'

Tags: python, unicode, typeerror, scrapy

This is my first Scrapy spider project.  I'm newer to Python so please forgive my ignorance.  Basically, I want to scrape the images from the www.doritos.com/products/ page.  I'm going to use these images for an object detection project so I'm building my training dataset.  Here's the code so far:

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider   
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from doritos.items import DoritosItem                   

class DoritosSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'doritos'
    allowed_domains = ['doritos.com']                                      
    start_urls = ['https://www.doritos.com']                               
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/products/.*']), 'parse_doritos')] 

    def parse_doritos(self, response):
            image = DoritosItem()
            image['title'] = response.xpath(["//img[@id='alt'/text()"]).extract() 
            rel = response.xpath('//product_thumbnail/@src').extract() 
            image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]                     
            return image
```

I checked these references to try and piece together an answer to my question. 
 I won't be surprised if the answer is in there, but my code is different enough to where I'm having a really hard time figuring this out:

[scrapy: request url must be str or unicode got list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906897/scrapy-request-url-must-be-str-or-unicode-got-list)

[Argument must be in bytes or unicode, got list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193624/argument-must-be-in-bytes-or-unicode-got-list)

[TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604847/typeerror-argument-1-must-be-a-string-or-unicode-object)

[Argument must be bytes or unicode, got '_Element'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832584/argument-must-be-bytes-or-unicode-got-element)

As I understand it from these references, I need to convert an argument in my function to a string.  Here is a screenshot of the traceback showing the error:
[SCRAPY Traceback Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH8cU.png)

I think it's on the second line of the parse_doritos function but I can't figure out the fix.  If anyone can help me work through this I'd really like to: a) get this thing to work, and b) understand where I went wrong and why your fix works.

Comment: Please post the error as code, not an image.

Comment: In general, screenshots can not be copied, won't appear in search engine results, and often cause problems for mobile users. Avoid them for any content that can be reasonably represented as text.

Comment: Aside from that, this is a well posed question. Welcome to Python and Stack Overflow.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't `response.xpath` be `response.selector.xpath` (twice)?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember response.xpath - doesn't accept list argument

```
def parse_doritos(self, response):
        image = DoritosItem()
        image['title'] = response.xpath(["//img[@id='alt'/text()"]).extract() # extra square brackets in response.xpath arguments - list argument instead of str
        rel = response.xpath('//product_thumbnail/@src').extract() # this function looks OK
        image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]                     
        return image
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're scraping the images from the website, I think you must `yield` every image (Scrapy will store them in an output file). Also, take in consideration that `extract()` method returns a list, even if your scraper finds a single element or doesn't find one at all. You may want to use `extract_first()`, this won't give a list but the value instead (it's the only place I can see which provides a list, maybe that is causing the problem).

EDIT: in your parser function, I think you should yield your `image` dict instead of returning it.

Comment: I updated the following code in my function to this and got the same error:<br/>

`def parse_doritos(self, response):<br/>
                image = DoritosItem()<br/>
                image['title'] = response.xpath(["//img[@id='alt'/text()"]).extractor_first() <br/>
                rel = response.xpath('//product_thumbnail/@src').extractor_first() <br/>
                image['image_urls'] = ['http:'+rel[0]]<br/>                    
                yield image`<br/>

Did I implement your idea correctly?

Comment: Sorry for the crap formatting.  I can't even seem to be able to figure out markdown!?!

Answer (score 0):

First, If I forget about your question and we focus on your work what you want, i think this might be very helpful to download images. [here, download images in scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html)

Second, if we talk about your question, your xpath to extract img source is fine but if you note it returns `/sites/doritos.com/files/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2018-08/new-blaze.png?itok=ZFZWWSIn` this link which afterwards you append only `http` while the orignal image link is `https://www.doritos.com/sites/doritos.com/files/styles/product_thumbnail/public/2018-08/collisions.png?itok=EZAydWWi`

You should use `urljoin` or prepend `https://www.doritos.com` as
`image['image_urls'] = ['https://www.doritos.com'+rel[0]]`